# Ethereum is not showing up in my ledger nano wallet from coin base

Tags: ledger-nano-s

I transferred my ethereum from my coin base account to my ledger nano wallet 15 hours ago and it is not showing up in my ledger nano wallet. It shows as transaction complete in coin base account and also shows in etherscan. How do I get it in my ledger nano wallet? I am sure about the address I copied from my ledger nano ethereum wallet. Still, how do I make sure that the address came out of my specific wallet? I am at a state of panic. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I sent eth from Binance to ledger on BSC and never received it. I checked with Binance and they said the transaction went through so have to check with the Ledger.com. I tried to look for the transaction on ethscan but was not showing, then thought maybe because it was on BSC. Messaged Ledger have not gotten back.
It doesn't make me feel very confident about moving coin off the exchange when it just disappears like this, and so little help once it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you sent to correct address and transaction is confirmed:

Be sure that your Ledger Nano interface is up-to-date and Ledger sync service is not down.

You don't have to panic as the only source of truth is the Ethereum blockchain itself. If you see your incoming balance on Etherscan, you have it. Relax.